# Unable to locate msodbcsql17

Tags: sql-server, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm trying to install mssql drivers in my Raspberry PI3 (raspbian 10, apache2 and php 7.3.4), I followed Microsoft instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 ,but when I run:

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
```

I got an error :

> Unable to locate package msodbcsql17

What did I miss ?

Thanks in advance.